# An estimate For the Laplacian semi-group

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $S(t)$ be the semi-group generated by the Dirichlet Laplacian in $L^2(0,1)$, which is given, for $y\in L^2(0,1)$, by

$$S(t)y=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^2\pi^2 t} \langle y,\sin(n\pi x) \rangle \sin(n\pi x).$$

For $t>0, y\in L^1(0,1),$ we have $\|S(t)y\|_{L^\infty}\le C t^{-\frac{1}{2}} \|y\|_{L^1(0,1)}$.

My question is about an **explicit value** of the constant $C$.

Thanks!